# preg_replace how to remove all numbers except alphanumeric

Tags: php, regex

How to remove all numbers exept alphanumeric, for example if i have string like this:

```
Abs_1234abcd_636950806858590746.lands
```

to become it like this

```
Abs_1234abcd_.lands
```

Comment: are underscore and period the only separators?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably done like this

Find  `(?i)(?<![a-z\d])\d+(?![a-z\d])`
Replace with nothing.

Explained:
*It's important to note that in the class `[a-z\d]` within assertions,

there exists a digit, without which could let "abc9`0123`4def" match.*

```
 (?i)                   # Case insensitive
 (?<! [a-z\d] )         # Behind, not a letter nor digit
 \d+                    # Many digits
 (?! [a-z\d] )          # Ahead, not a letter nor digit
```

---

Note - a speedier version exists  `(?i)\d(?<!\d[a-z\d])\d*(?![a-z\d])`

---

```
Regex1:   (?i)\d(?<!\d[a-z\d])\d*(?![a-z\d])
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    0.53 s,   530.56 ms,   530564 µs
Matches per sec:   188,478


Regex2:   (?i)(?<![a-z\d])\d+(?![a-z\d])
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    0.91 s,   909.58 ms,   909577 µs
Matches per sec:   109,941
```

Comment: how to replace last _. with dot only?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example, we can simply use `_` as a left boundary and `.` as the right boundary, collect our digits, and replace:

#### Test

```
$re = '/(.+[_])[0-9]+(\..+)/m';
$str = 'Abs_1234abcd_636950806858590746.lands';
$subst = '$1$2';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9MpFmP/1/)

Answer (score 1):

For your example data, you could also match not a word character or an underscore `[\W_]`  using a character class. Then forget what is matched using `\K`.

Match 1+ digits that you want to replace with a empty string and assert what is on the right is again not a word character or an underscore.

```
[\W_]\K\d+(?=[\W_])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/efYlex/1)

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '\'

Comment: @Tod Did you try it like this? https://3v4l.org/4c4gl Did you add delimiters `/`around the pattern?  `/[\W_]\K\d+(?=[\W_])/`